# inhomogeneous Ornstein-Ulhenbeck process / invariant probability measure

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\gamma$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ and consider the real valued inhomogeneous Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process satisfying 
$$
d X_t = -\gamma_t X_t d t + d W_t, \quad X_0 = x \in \mathbb{R}.  
$$
Assume that $\gamma_t \geq \nu > 0$. It seems reasonable to believe that $X_t$ has an invariant probability measure which should be gaussian.
Indeed, a quick calculation gives
$$
X_t = x \exp \left ( - \int_0^t \gamma_s d s\right ) 
+ \int_0^t \exp \left ( - \int_s^t \gamma_u d u\right ) d W_s. 
$$
In order to identify the variance of the limiting gaussian variable, we shall need to calculate 
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}  \exp \left ( -2 \int_0^t \gamma_s d s \right ) \int_0^t \exp \left ( 2\int_0^s \gamma_u d u\right ) d s.
$$
**Question** Is this limit easily computable?
I am expecting something which looks like (I may be wrong)
$$
\frac{1}{2 \Gamma}
$$
where
$$
\Gamma \triangleq \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \gamma_s d s.
$$

Comment: I think the $+2$ and $-2$ in the two exponents where you take the limit $t\rightarrow\infty$ should be interchanged, see the answer below.

Comment: Indeed, they have to be interchanged. thank you. it is updated.

Answer (score 3):

If we define
$$\Omega(t)= \exp \left (- 2 \int_0^t \gamma_s d s \right ) \int_0^t \exp \left (  2\int_0^s \gamma_u d u\right ) d s,$$
then this function satisfies the differential equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Omega(t)=1-2\gamma_t\,\Omega(t).$$
The limit $t\rightarrow\infty$ of $\Omega(t)$ exists if $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\gamma_t=\Gamma>0$ exists, and is then equal to
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\Omega(t)=\frac{1}{2\Gamma}.$$